# Remote Registry List of PCs

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to get remote registry values from `OEMInformation` key from a list of computers, but cant seem to get it to work. I get this error:

`Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found"`

What am i missing?

```
$strMachineName = import-csv C:\temp\PCs.txt
foreach ($line in $strMachineName)
{
    try {
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)
$regkey=$reg.OpenSubkey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OemInformation')
 'MODEL:{0}  Manufactured by:"{1}"' -f $regkey.GetValue('Model'),$regkey.GetValue('Manufacturer')

}   

Catch{
           Write-Host "$_"  -fore red
     }
 }
$results|Export-Csv C:\temp\PCs-Results.csv -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$Computer`-variable you are referring to in the following line, doesn't exist.

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)
```

Does the content of your txt-file have a header? Ex:

```
Computer
Machine1
Machine2
```

then try

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Line.Computer)
```

If your txt-file only contains one machinename per line and no headers, then replace your `Import-CSV` with `Get-Content` and try

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Line)
```

Comment: thank you. Sorry newbie here. So it got to show on the command prompt but the PC name is missing next to the results..??

Comment: I haven't used `OpenRemoteBaseKey()` before, but I don't think it's supposed to show the computer name in the results. If you need that,then you need to append it to the result-object using ex. `$regkey | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $line` and then access the new `$regkey.ComputerName` property